# How can I approximate the standard error for an elasticity with limited information?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, elasticity

I want to estimate/approximate the standard error of an elasticity of Y with respect to X: (dy/dx)*(x/y)

Let's say I have the following data:

- The mean of Y and its standard deviation
- The mean of X
- dy/dx and its standard error (e.g. a coefficient from a linear regression)

How can I approximate the standard error of the elasticity using only this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need all the covariances between the coefficients, so you cannot do this with the data given.

The elasticity in even a simple univariate model like $E[y \vert x] = \alpha + \beta x$ is $$\frac{\partial E[y \vert x]}{\partial x} \cdot\frac{x}{E[y \vert x]}=\beta \cdot \frac{x}{\alpha+\beta x}=\frac{\beta}{\frac{\alpha}{x}+\beta}.$$

This is a ratio of two functions of random variables, $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Call the denominator $\eta$. Using a Taylor series expansion, you can [show](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/files/ratio.pdf) that

$$Var \left( \frac{\beta}{\eta} \right) \approx \frac{Var(\beta)}{\eta^2}-\frac{2 \cdot \beta}{\eta^3}\cdot Cov(\beta,\eta)+\frac{\beta^2}{\eta^4}\cdot Var(\eta)$$

You need the covariance between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to calculate the last two terms. Your proposal to treat $\frac{x}{\hat y}$ as constant amounts to ignoring those two terms, which will usually understate your variance.

Here's an example showing this empirically in Stata:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. regress price mpg

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 72)        =     20.26
       Model |   139449474         1   139449474   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   495615923        72  6883554.48   R-squared       =    0.2196
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2087
       Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =    2623.7

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |  -238.8943   53.07669    -4.50   0.000    -344.7008   -133.0879
       _cons |   11253.06   1170.813     9.61   0.000     8919.088    13587.03
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, eyex(mpg)

Average marginal effects                        Number of obs     =         74
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
ey/ex w.r.t. : mpg

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      ey/ex   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |  -.9859019   .3341136    -2.95   0.004    -1.651945   -.3198587
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. predict double yhat, xb

. gen double ME    = _b[mpg]*(mpg/yhat)

. gen double se_ME = _se[mpg]*(mpg/yhat)

. sum ME se_ME

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
          ME |         74   -.9859019    .8551006  -6.716071   -.341834
       se_ME |         74    .2190441    .1899832   .0759474   1.492153
```

The correct SE should be 0.3341136. The one you get is by ignoring that $\hat y$ is random is 0.2190441, which is 2/3rds the right size. Note that average marginal effects do match here.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I really appreciate your thorough response!

Answer (score 0):

This is insufficient information. You need the covariance of $X$, $Y$, and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$ in order to generate some usable information. See also the multivariate delta method.

Comment: Thanks, AdamO. Do you know how inaccurate it would be if I were to treat X and Y as constants and use var(C*(dy/dx)) = C^2 * var(dy/dx)?

p.s. how did you write equation notation? I'm new to stack exchange...

Comment: @KrisB. First Q: Can't say anything in general, depends on functional form and actual variance of assumed constants. Did you read about delta method? Second Q: It's LaTeX. Press edit in any Q to see how markdown is written.