# How to calculate the standard error (SE) of the x*y, knowing x_SE and y_SE?

Tags: standard-error

The standard error (SE) of x and y are x_SE and y_SE, respectively. If z=x*y, what is the z_SE?

Comment: This comes up [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307682/7071). You will need the covariance between the x and y (unless you can assume it is zero).

Comment: Hope you formulate your question more carefully. For example, why standard error, instead of standard deviation (or variance) is asked?

Comment: because the OriginPro gives me the SE, not SD, after curve fitting